# Ubuntu: Редирект домена через NS запись

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, hosting, configuration, cross-domain

Привет.

Я видел у знакомых такую структуру:

```
домен 1 ---> |
домен 2 ---> | домен 0 ---> сервер
домен 3 ---> |
...
```

Домены (1,2,3) ссылаются на домен 0, при это в доменах (1,2,3) прописано только NS.домен0.com. Т.е. выходит очень удобно, нужно при появлении нового домена добавить только одну запись в NS.домен0.com в NS нового домена.

У меня не получается повторить такой трюк. C Домен 0 - сайт могу открыть, с Домен 1 нет. Во моем случае:

1. Сервер - 185.174.173.169
2. Домен 0 - loustfillmstv.pw
3. Домен 1 - joyukasonos.pw

/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost loustfillmstv.pw:80>                                                                                                                                  
        ServerName loustfillmstv.pw                                                                                                                                
        ServerAlias www.loustfillmstv.pw                                                                                                                           
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost                                                                                                                            
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html                                                                                                                                 
</VirtualHost>                                                                                                                                                     

<VirtualHost joyukasonos.pw:80>                                                                                                                                    
        ServerName joyukasonos.pw                                                                                                                                  
        ServerAlias www.joyukasonos.pw                                                                                                                             
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html                                                                                                                                 
</VirtualHost>
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: `loustfillmstv.pw` отлично работает, а для доменного имени `joyukasonos.pw` указаны nameserver-ы, имена которых резолвятся в один и тот же ip-адрес 185.174.173.169, который не отвечает на dns-запросы.

Comment: Что нужно сделать?

Comment: я — не знаю. ведь довольно сложно понять, чего вы хотите добиться, отправляя клиентов на неработающий dns-сервер. есть гипотеза, что ваш вопрос — про [srv-запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C), но это всего лишь гипотеза, ведь вы же об этом не упомянули ни пол-словом.

Comment: нужно чтобы работало как на схеме, т.е. на новых доменах прописывался только NS домен 0, а домен 0 чтобы отправлял на ip сервера.

Comment: ясней, увы, не стало: вы повторили то же, что и в вопросе. чего вы хотите добиться с помощью **неработающего** nameserver-а — остаётся загадкой.

Comment: так нужно для задачи

Comment: плохо сформулирован вопрос. вроде как автор понимает, что такое dns-сервер и что такое веб-сервер -- а валит всё в кучу. и я даже не знаю, как этот клубок распутывать: по-хорошему нужно понять уровень спрашивающего, вроде слова правильные знает, но соединяя их вместе получается сплошная каша. вопрос предлагаю закрыть как "непонятна суть вопроса", а автору предлагаю подумать над вопросом забыв, что у него есть апач. до настройки апача ещё километры пути: надо сначала разобраться с неработающим DNS. Рисовать до просветления схемы "у них" и "у меня", пока не станет ясно, что не в апаче дело.